# Why can't I insert an element at specified index with a Vector?

Tags: java, data-structures

I tried

```
cache = new Vector<CacheBlock>(1024);
...
cache.add(10, blk); // gives index out of bounds
```

So is it impossible to insert (into specified index) into an empty list? Or how might I fill up all elements if the Vector, with null or otherwise, so I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [setSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize%28int%29) to make sure your cache is big enough before you insert elements:

> setSize
>
> public void setSize(int newSize)
>
> Sets the size of this vector. If the new size is greater than the current size, 
>   new null items are added to the end of the vector. If
>   the new size is less than the current size, all components at index
>   newSize and greater are discarded.

```
cache = new Vector<CacheBlock>(1024);
cache.setSize(11);
cache.add(10, blk);
```

Comment: Oh please make sure you are not truncating the vector before you setSize!

Answer (score 2):

Vectors are contiguous. They must have elements at **each** index from 0 to size-1. There cannot be any gaps. Thus you cannot insert at an index outside the current bounds of the vector because that would leave *holes*.

So, if you want to insert at index 10, you have to first ensure that the list is populated with at least 10 items. You can use [setSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize%28int%29) to do this (emphasis mine):

> Sets the size of this vector. If the new size is greater than the current size, **new null items are added to the end of the
>   vector**.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why you cannot insert directly at arbitrary positions.